# <li> dropdown not properly formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm going to insert a language to my MVC 5 project.In UI part i need to add languge dropdowns sections,In my Original theme HTML code shows like this,

```
<div id="lang_sel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="lang_sel_sel icl-en" href="#">EN</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="icl-fr">
                    <a href="#">FR</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icl-de">
                    <a href="#">DE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icl-nl">
                    <a href="#">NL</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then for my requirement i change it to the following code,

```
<div id="lang_sel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="lang_sel_sel icl-en" href="@Url.LangSwitcher("English", ViewContext.RouteData, "en")">EN</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="icl-fr">
                    <a href="@Url.LangSwitcher("Italy", ViewContext.RouteData, "it")">Italy</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In here my dropdown not correctly created.

Comment: it seems you generate only 1 dropdown item. Is that a problem?

Comment: @KhanhTO when i make a change it shows me like this Link >https://screenshots.firefox.com/PGv0KDR3I0rRVlSm/localhost

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? And what is your `@Url.LangSwitcher()` extension method

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should escape some quotes as this line:

```
<a href="@Url.LangSwitcher("Italy", ViewContext.RouteData, "it")">Italy</a>
```

will make the link url as `@Url.LangSwitcher(`

and sorry, this should be a comment, but formatting this in the comment is a chore

Comment: as far as i remember, escaping quotes in MVC is to double it, for example `<a href="@Url.LangSwitcher(""Italy"", ViewContext.RouteData, ""it"")">Italy</a>`

Comment: what is the result of `<a href="#">@Url.LangSwitcher("Italy", ViewContext.RouteData, "it")</a>` ?

Comment: It shows me like this .. See this Link > https://screenshots.firefox.com/PGv0KDR3I0rRVlSm/localhost

Comment: looks more like a CSS problem to me, maybe you could play arround with the CSS